# MySQL функции, встроенные функции триггеры и т.п

Tags: mysql

За всю свою небольшую карьеру веб разработчика я использовал БД только для вставки, изменения, удаления и запроса информации. Ну максимум я использовал вложенные селекты, оператор LIKE. Все остальные манипуляции я производил в коде бекенда.

Но у MySQL есть встроенные функции, возможность писать [свои процедуры и функции](http://www.zoonman.ru/library/mysql_sr_and_t.htm).

Уважаемые разработчики, объясните мне пожалуйста:

1) Где, в каких ситуациях применимы хотя бы встроенные функции, и  почему их стоит использовать?

2) Моя ли это компетенция (бекенд разработчик)?

Comment: Принято считать, что хранимые процедуры работают быстрее (как минимум, можно уменьшить количество RTT). На практике я не могу сказать, что они сильно нужны. Иногда требуется выполнить какую-то операцию над значением в таблице (e.g. проверить каждую запись на две регулярки сразу), и в этом случае проще будет пройтись своей функцией по каждой, но лично я обычно подхожу к таким проблемам с другой стороны.

Comment: Функции в БД могут на пример позволить организавать дополнительную защиту данных, когда приложение вообще не имеет доступа к определенным таблицам, а вся работа сводится к обращениям к процедурам. Кроме того есть на моей старой работе несколько приложений которые имеют и клиентские Win приложения и web-интерфейс и в какое то время был терминальный доступ по RS232 портам. это все написано на разных языках в виде независимых модулей. Вот там практически вся бизнес логика в БД, дабы не повторять ее в разных вариантах на разных платформах, т.е. по сути бакэнд часть - это БД

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже отписались в комментариях, они быстрее работают и позволяют организовать довольно хитрую логику работы над данными со своими сценариями.
Существует не повсеместная практика (иногда оправданная), когда инженеры СУБД описывают в виде хранимых процедур все операции с базой данных и предоставляют их бэкэнд разработчикам в качестве АПИ. Соответственно, бэкэндер в базу по сути и не лезет, за правильность каждого отдельного запроса не отвечает, и вообще сосредоточен на других задачах, занимаясь бизнес-логикой приложения и практически не думая о слое хранения данных. Так разработчик знает, что для получения данных о продажах за месяц, он дергает процедуру *Х*, а для инициации закрытия финансового периода, он дергает процедуру *Y*.

В то же время, хранимый процедуры (в частности *MySql*) очень туго поддаются отладке, плюс они все таки содержат часть бизнес-логики, т.е. что происходит в Вашей программе, становится далеко не очевидно, исходя из кода приложения. Самый ад начинается, если часть один и тот же аспект бизнес-логики отображается и в коде, и в хранимой процедуре, что в иной раз можно наблюдать в проектах с большим к-вом *legacy*  кода. Когда какой-то разработчик писал хранимые процедуры, потом ушел из комманды, никто другой из членов комманды писать их не умел, и в дальнейшем они продолжили писать проект, не используя процедуры, вынося их логику в приложения, но не отрефакторив нормально код. Проходит время, на проект набирают новую комманду, и ей необходимо изменения в бизнес-логике дублировать в нескольких разных местах приложения плюс в хранимой процедуре.

В настоящее время, бэкэнд-разработчики, как правило, сидят обложившись различными ORM и на этом зачастую их взаимодействие с базой заканчивается. Если у Вас на проекте есть отдельный человек, который готов писать и поддерживать хранимые процедуры, предоставляя Вам лишь описаный интерфейс - при правильной организации это может пойти на пользу разработке. Пытаться от нечего делать начинать использовать хранимые процедуры в боевом проекте, который до этого обходился без них, я бы не советовал.